# Can I start development of wehcat mini program and test servers without ICP licensed domain name?

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram, wechat-auth

I am currently working on wechat mini-program, I have created an account, chosen a server to store data I ll be fetching, but have not got an ICP licensed domain name, because it takes about a month to get. I want to know if I can already start development and send/receive a server request from my app in a test environment? Or do I have to get an ICP license and domain name first?

Answer (score 0):

It's not  necessary if you just want a test environment.But your can't submit your application online.
Editing the "project.config.json" in root of program.Ensuring the parameter named "urlCheck" as false.You request will work.